# Redirect after Post in Lift

Tags: lift

After searching through SO, and not finding anything useful, I decided to post this question.

Is it possible to execute the "Redirect after Post" idiom in Lift - and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

One thing to notice, is that in order to avoid "form resubmission" warning, we need to redirect to **ourselves** when we want to show things like errors or notices, as per the [mail archive discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/liftweb@googlegroups.com/msg17914.html) by Naftoli Gugenheim:

```
If you are using a StatefulSnippet call redirectTo(S.uri) on in to load the 
same page with the same snippet instance.
```

So, for example when processing a form we can do something like this:

```
def process() = {
    if (patientName== "Joe") {
      S.error("Joe not allowed!")
    }
    val dateRegex="\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d";

    if (!birthdate.matches(dateRegex)) {
      S.error("birthdate", "Invalid date. Please enter date in the form dd/mm/yyyy.")
    }

    S.errors match {
        //Redirect on success
        case Nil =>S.notice("Patient name: " + patientName); S.redirectTo("/")
        //Redirect to ourselves - and show errors
        case _ =>S.redirectTo(S.uri)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `S.redirectTo("\pagename")` after proceesing post request. For that to work you need to define "pagename" in menu.